# From FLAC file get cover image and display it on a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, flac

I'm trying to code a media player to learn and practice Python, what I'm currently trying to do is to display the cover of the FLAC file in a window and manage to do so seperatedly from the media player with this code:

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC, Picture
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os.path


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
cont1 = 0


songs = ['03 - Vimana.flac', 'Haddaway - What Is Love (70 Mix).flac']

def  getCoverFlac(flac_file):
    flacObj = FLAC(flac_file)
    coverArt = flacObj.pictures
    coverName = str(flac_file)+"Cover.jpg"
    if os.path.isfile(coverName):
        print(coverName+" already exists")
    else:
        for img in coverArt:
            if img.type == 3:
                with open(coverName, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(img.data)
                print(coverName+" created and saved")
    return coverName


img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(getCoverFlac(songs[1])))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

The real problem began when I tried to use this function with the media player code below, tried to adapt my function so the cover image would work like the *song_title* label, I think the problem is this piece of code:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(getCoverFlac(var.get())))
```

I think since it gets like executed when *var* is empty, my function doesn't know what to do with it(tried to make a condition inside the function for this, but it still couldn't return a *coverName*), so I want to know what should I change or learn to achieve the goal of displaying the name of the song being play + its cover.
Here the complete code:

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tkr
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os
from mutagen.flac import FLAC, Picture
import os.path
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

music_player = tkr.Tk()
cont = 0
music_player.title("My Music Player")
music_player.geometry("600x600")
play_list = tkr.Listbox(music_player, font="Helvetica 12 bold", bg='yellow', selectmode=tkr.SINGLE)


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play_list.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    var.set(play_list.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print(var.get())
def stop():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
def pause():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
def unpause():
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
def selectDir():
    directory = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(directory)
    song_list = os.listdir()
    
    
    for item in song_list:
        pos = 0
        play_list.insert(pos, item)
        pos += 1
def  getCoverFlac(flac_file):
        flacObj = FLAC(flac_file)
        coverArt = flacObj.pictures
        coverName = str(flac_file)+"Cover.jpg"
        if os.path.isfile(coverName):
            print(coverName+" already exists")
        else:
            for img in coverArt:
                if img.type == 3:
                    with open(coverName, "wb") as f:
                        f.write(img.data)
                    print(coverName+" created and saved")
        return coverName
    

Button1 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="PLAY", command=play, bg="blue", fg="white")
Button2 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="STOP", command=stop, bg="red", fg="white")
Button3 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="PAUSE", command=pause, bg="purple", fg="white")
Button4 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="UNPAUSE", command=unpause, bg="orange", fg="white")
Button5 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="Music Dir", command=selectDir, bg="green", fg="white")



var = tkr.StringVar() 

song_title = tkr.Label(music_player, font="Helvetica 12 bold", textvariable=var)

if var.get == "":
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('romani.gif'))
else:
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(getCoverFlac(var.get())))
    
panel = tkr.Label(music_player, image = img)

song_title.pack()
panel.pack(fill="x")
Button1.pack(fill="x")
Button2.pack(fill="x")
Button3.pack(fill="x")
Button4.pack(fill="x")
Button5.pack(fill="x")
play_list.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
music_player.mainloop()
```

My last attemp to fix this was the:

```
if var.get == "":
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('romani.gif'))
else:
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(getCoverFlac(var.get())))
```

Console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 251, in _openfile
    fileobj = open(filename, "rb+" if writable else "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Code\python\Media player\mediap.py", line 70, in <module>
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(getCoverFlac(var.get())))
  File "d:\Code\python\Media player\mediap.py", line 41, in getCoverFlac
    flacObj = FLAC(flac_file)
  File "C:\Users\abrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_file.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 154, in wrapper
    with _openfile(self, filething, filename, fileobj,
  File "C:\Users\abrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\abrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 272, in _openfile
    raise MutagenError(e)
mutagen.MutagenError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

It was probably a messy way of asking and I apologize beforehand to those taking their time to read, Its my first time trying to do a project outside of school assignments and I'm beat, didn't know what was exactly my problem so I didn't know what was the correct question, so I rather explained what was I trying to do, what I did and what I got, thanks for your time.

Comment: `var.get` in `if var.get == ""` is a function reference, not the value in the variable.  You need to use `if var.get() == ""` instead.  However what do you expect the value of `var.get()`?  It should be empty when you use it in the `if` statement.

Comment: yeah Im expecting it to be empty, what I wanted to accomplish with that was to run the ```else``` part when it was not empty, like the *song_title* that updates itself every time you pick a song.

Comment: But it is *always* empty when you put the if/else block at that position.  You should put if/else block inside a function which is called whenever you want.

Comment: thanks, will try to implement it that way and see how it goes.